# setxkbmap configuration

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, executable, keyboard-layout

I'm using Lubuntu 13.04 without executing `lxpanel` (I killed it on purpose because I don't want to use it for the project I'm working on now). The problem is that, without `lxpanel` executing, the run prompt (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) doesn't work, and I need a way to execute programs hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> without `lxpanel` being executed.

Diggin' on the internet I found that you can configure your keyboard with *setxkbmap*, for example with: *setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp*, you terminate the session. I'm trying to make something like this: `setxkbmap -option execute:alt_f2`, but it doesn't work. Does anybody know the list of available options for the `-option` attribute and if the option "execute" is available? Do you know if there's a way to do this?

Comment: All of the options are listed at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was searching for! I can't do what I want, so I will execute LXpanel and hide it.

Answer (score 3):

No, setxkbmap can't do that. XKB is a facility to manage the keyboard layout, not keyboard shortcuts. Its job is to translate hardware key events into software key events and characters, for example to decide that when the keyboard sends key code 38 this should correspond to the logical key `A` and should insert the character `a` without <kbd>Shift</kbd> and `A` with <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

There are a few special pseudo-keys that are interpreted directly by the X server, providing commands such as simulating mouse events or killing the server. But that's limited to actions performed by the X server. There is no way to do anything like starting a program. In fact, Linux's display mechanism, the [X11 window system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11#Software_architecture), has a client-server architecture and the server (the part that manages the screen) might not even be running on the same machine as the clients (GUI applications, including the [window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) and other parts of the [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment)).

In order to display the run dialog that you normally get with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, you need to execute a client program. Executing a program is normally the realm of the window manager or some other part of the desktop environment. If you want to define keyboard shortcuts without depending on your WM/DE, you can use [XBindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/) ([Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/xbindkeys), [Arch tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys)).

I'm not familiar with LXDE; if you need help setting it up, you can ask a new question on this site. As far as I know, though, the run dialog is built into LXPanel, so you'd need to run LXPanel to get it.

Comment: Thanks you. You were right and I can't do what I wanted, so I executed LXpanel and hide it. That was the best way to do it.